# How do create delegate to display icon and text of QComboBox in QTreeWidget (PyQt)?

Tags: qt, delegates, pyqt, qcombobox

I've been having some trouble trying to display icon and text in QTreeWidget . My QTreeWidget just display text!! how use paint method for display icon and text ？Thank you very much!the Code is as following:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys
class ColorComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):   
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(ColorComboBox,self).__init__(parent)
        colorList=['yellow','red']       
        for color in colorList:
            pix=QtGui.QPixmap(QtCore.QSize(20,20))
            pix.fill(QtGui.QColor(color))
            self.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(pix),color)           
class CustomsDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(CustomsDelegate,self).__init__(parent)       
    def paint(self,painter,option,index):
        painter.save()                  
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white))
        value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        if value.isValid():
            text = value.toString() 
            painter.drawText(option.rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, text)    
        painter.restore()
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        self.combo = ColorComboBox(parent)
        return self.combo    
    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
        editor.setCurrentIndex(editor.findText(value))        

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if editor.currentIndex() >= 0:
            realidx = editor.model().index(editor.currentIndex(), 0) 
            value = editor.model().data(realidx)        
            model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)                              
class B(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(B,self).__init__(parent)            
        self.setColumnCount(2)      
        x = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
        x.setText(0,'text1')   
        y = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()     
        x.setFlags(x.flags()|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        self.addTopLevelItems([x,y])
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(1,CustomsDelegate(self))     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    b = B()
    b.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

For any of the standard views, getting an icon in not the job of the delegate. The standard way of getting an icon into a view is by returning a `QIcon` whenever the view calls `data(index, Qt::DecorationRole)`

Put your icon code into your model and the view will take care of itself.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was also trying to use the paint method, so I'm pleased to discover it's much easier -- but it's "DecorationRole" (`QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole`).  I took the liberty of editing your answer.